# data cleaning procedures

Tags: data-preprocessing

If you were provided with a sample data set as follows:

| Date | Open | High | Low | Close | Adj Close | Signal |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 202106-01 | 627.80 | 633.80 | 620.55 | 620.55 | 623.90 | 85.11 |
| 2021-06-02 | 620.13 | 623.36 | 599.14 | 620.13 | 605.12 | 76.59 |
| 2021-06-03 | 601.80 | 604.55 | 571.22 | 571.22 | 572.84 | 68.73 |
| 2021-06-04 | 579.71 | 600.61 | 577.20 | 600.61 | 599.05 | 78.47 |
| 2021-06-07 | 591.83 | 610.00 | 582.88 | 610.00 | 605.13 | 78.63 |

and so on for some few weeks. No further information have been provided.

How would you "review the quality of the data, list any potential errors, and propose corrected values. Please list each quality check error and correction applied."

Does anyone have any pointers on any possible data quality procedure that I could have applied?

Thank you for your kind suggestions.